# Coinbase, Bitpay and Bitcoin Core

Tags: coinbase.com

A website shows their services can be purchased via Coinbase and Bitpay.

I searched for information and found Bitcoin Core from bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet and I think it is very popular among tens of wallet platforms.

What is the difference between Coinbase and Bitcoin Core? Is there any thing one can do but the other can not?
If I used an account with Bitcoin Core, will I be able to purchase their services?

There are also Dogecoin, Blackcoin and etc accepted by that company. What made people buying these new kind of coins rather than using Bitcoins?

Answer (score 1):

Coinbase.com is a company that buys and sells bitcoins, as well as offers a service to manage your bitcoins for you, much like a bank manages your USD for you.

On the other hand, Bitcoin Core is a software that allows you to manage your bitcoins yourself. Bitcoin Core is not a company, so you cannot purchase any services from them.

Answer (score 1):

Coinbase and Bitpay are companies that offer payment processing services for other companies, like the website you mention. They manage for them all the things related with the payments in Bitcoin. Usually the business will open an account with them and they will provide tools to accept Bitcoin in the website. They will store the bitcoins for the business, send them where it says or even exchange them for dollars or euros if that is what the business wants.

Bitcoin Core, on the other side, is a wallet. A business can use it to store its bitcoins if it wanted, but it doesn't have anything that will facilitate accepting Bitcoin in a website (except having an address). A good practice for anyone accepting Bitcoin payments through a payment processor is to have them sent to the business local wallet (which could be Bitcoin Core or any other) after the purchase. This way, the business has full control of those coins instead of having them stored by the payment processor.

A user can also use the Bitcoin Core wallet. When trying to purchase from a website that accepts Bitcoin, you will get an address to which you have to send the payment. That you can do from Bitcoin Core or any other wallet you use.

Incidentally, Coinbase also offers something similar to a wallet to anyone who wants it. I say "similar to a wallet" because they have a system in which they keep control of the bitcoins, not the user, so it can't be really called a wallet. It is just a website that lets you manage bitcoins that are tied to the account you have there, but they have the custody of the funds.

Answer (score -1):

Try Circle Pay if you are residing in US https://www.circle.com
This service costs nothing and it does not need much information of yours to run

Circle Internet is the brainchild of Fintech on their path to disrupt legacy payment platforms

With circle you accept/send fiat or cryptocurrency via email, text, hash and it stays in the currency of your choice USD or BTC. For example we worked together on a project in France and now we are back in the US but you are in NY and I'm in LA. I still owe you for a tab you picked up. With circle I can send you the the money via BTC blockchain and it will still come out as fiat on your side..amazing dont you think...oh yeah.. no fees and connect to your US bank seamlessly.

Comment: Is there some purpose to that picture that I'm overlooking? It's ginormous and doesn't seem to reinforce any specific point in your answer. Please consider removing it.